# How to execute karate script for only changed microservices

Tags: karate

I am running in a problem wherein I have to run only the karate API scripts for which developers have deployed their scripts so the expectation here from the development side is that only run the karate regression suite for the services which deployed in a particular release. 
If I clear my question here; if we have 5 microservices karate scripts which are supposed to run in every release in UAT like below:

```
1. A microservice
 2. B microservice
 3. C microservice
 4. D microservice
 5. E microservice
```

Here, the dev team made changes in A & E microservices and asked to execute only scripts that run A & E microservice without touching karate test runner class from where we are supposed to execute the feature files.
so my question is how I will make karate understands to identify first the changed target microservice dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate has no way to dynamically derive this. You can in theory write some Java code to figure this out and then build a list of features to run. This cannot be built into Karate because it depends on many factors, your server-side architecture for example.

What most teams do is use tags: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

So you tag all the tests related to A, B, C etc and now you can run any combination of tests.

Comment: I have one idea on which I will be working on further. Once done will let the forum knows about it.
Thanks!